# What is the proper course when answering own question?

Tags: discussion

Given a question where the submitter answers his or her own question, are they supposed to answer their own question, or update their question with their resolution? Does a moderator have to do anything to it if they don't answer their own question? Should it be flagged?

An example, at the time of posting the question included the resolution, but remained unanswered formally: [Cannot refresh marker manager (Gmap v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409344/cannot-refresh-marker-manager-gmap-v3)

Not completely sure what the proper course of action is here, for either the submitter, or somebody who views a question which has been answered by the submitter in improper form, or what the proper form really even is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The right thing to do is post an answer on a question if you know how to solve it, even if the question is your own. In this case, you can try leaving a comment asking the OP to do that; if they don't you can post it as an answer yourself and revert the change to the question (the answer shouldn't be part of the question). You don't need a mod for anything; there's nothing special they can do to fix it