# When to mark something vague as an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I wish I could mark something as 'half an answer'.

In [Practical (Django) Caching Strategy & Implementation? Cache long, Invalidate cache upon data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522180/practical-django-caching-strategy-implementation-cache-long-invalidate-cach), I ask a rather vague question, and get an [even more vague answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522180/practical-django-caching-strategy-implementation-cache-long-invalidate-cach/7531007#7531007) that only partially answers the question.
I'd like to post up the method and code that I wrote to solve the problem; the Answer was a help, but it is not all the way there, and it is not really a best practice. I got the rest of the way on my own, and I'm tired of answering my own questions.

So what's the etiquette for these situations? Do I add my own answer, edit the one that is already there, or should I do nothing?

Comment: Cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107001/is-it-appropriate-to-answer-ones-own-question-with-code-derived-from-another-ans http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/my-improved-answer-based-on-anothers-accepted-answer-for-my-own-question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107405/what-is-the-proper-course-when-answering-own-question/107406#107406

Comment: I know this question is pretty old, but I would love to add a point here. What if even YOU didn't find a solution so auto-answer is not possible? would you then mark the mostly-usefull "answer" even if it doesn't answer the question/resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean, you're "tired of answering [your] own questions"? You solved the problem you had, which was the *point of posting* the question, right? Don't you answer your own questions all day long while you're working?

> the Answer was a help, but it is not all the way there, and it is not really a best practice.

Great! Upvote it and leave a comment explaining why you think it's not best practice (maybe the poster will revise or explain in turn), and mention that you've found a solution.

> Do I add my own answer ...?

If you have the exact solution to your problem, and you believe it would be helpful to other readers, then yes, absolutely. You might mention that the other answer was helpful, too. See: [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

[Your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107632/when-to-mark-something-vague-as-an-answer/107635#comment277041_107635) below Lance's answer:

> ...but I guess I feel a bit like an Answer-whore since the OP did help a bit.

[Bounties are a great way to "tip"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers/36581#36581) an answerer when you don't feel like a single upvote is enough.

Answer (score 6):

Upvote the answer, but don't accept it.

Comment: So do I answer my own question with my method & code and accept *that*?

Comment: Yes, if you have the answer, do just that.  Self-answering and acceptance is just fine on SO.

Comment: yeah if you look at my history you'll see I'm fine with that :-/  but I guess I feel a bit like an Answer-whore since the OP did help a bit.

Comment: @Dave: the answer to that may be [a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/how-come-no-option-to-tip-answerers/36581#36581).

Answer (score 1):

Normally the community *regulates* vague questions and closes them. So if you ask a vague question you cannot expect an objective and precise answer. If you are not satisfied with the answer that was provided to you, you could still update your question and provide more details in order to make it more focused. If still you don't get a satisfying answer, and still your question is not closed, and you have found a solution to this problem, you post this solution and accept it. This way people that might be having the same *vague problem* as you in the future might find your solution helpful.

And if you are tired of not getting answers to your *vague* questions, maybe you should change the way you ask them and make them *less vague*.

Comment: It was an architecture / is this practical? question, so it's hard to be less vague other than 'please write my code for me'.  But I'll try.

Comment: @Dave, architecture is always vague :-) If it wasn't, software development would have been the easiest business in the world.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the existing answer to change its meaning is not what I would suggest. I would rather write my own question, reporting that thanks to the answer given from the other user I was able to find my own question.